# ERROR: expected identifier or '(' in xcode ios 5

Tags: xcode, bounce

xcode 4.2 ios 5 single view template

I am very new to this ios format and these new features in xcode

Here is all of my code:

```
#import "SimpleGame2ViewController.h"

#define kStateRunning 1
#define kStateGameOver 2

#define kLeftDown 1
#define kRightDown 2
#define kTouchesEnded 3

#define kPlatformWidth 55
#define kPlatformHeight 16

#define kMaxBallSpeed 10

#define kJumpPower 9

#define kGravity 0.195

@ implementation SimpleGame2ViewController @ synthesize ball;
@synthesize platform1;
@synthesize platform2;
@synthesize platform3;
@synthesize platform4;
@synthesize platform5;
@synthesize bg;
@synthesize gameState;
@synthesize ballVelocity, gravity;
@synthesize touchState;

-(void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Release any cached data, images, etc that aren't in use.
}

#pragma mark - View lifecycle

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    gameState = kStateRunning;
    ballVelocity = CGPointMake(0, 0);
    gravity = CGPointMake(0, kGravity);

    [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval: 1.0 / 60
        target: self
        selector: @selector(gameloop)
        userInfo: nil
        repeats:YES];

    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

-(void)gameloop {
    if (gameState == kStateRunning) {
        [self gameStatePlayNormal];
    } else if (gameState == kStateGameOver) {
        ballVelocity.x = 0;
        ballVelocity.y = 0;

        ball.center = CGPointMake(152 + 16, 326 + 16);
        platform1.center =
            CGPointMake(129 + (kPlatformWidth / 2),
                414 + (kPlatformHeight / 2));
        platform2.center =
            CGPointMake(34 + (kPlatformWidth / 2),
                316 + (kPlatformHeight / 2));
        platform3.center =
            CGPointMake(192 + (kPlatformWidth / 2),
                261 + (kPlatformHeight / 2));
        platform4.center =
            CGPointMake(146 + (kPlatformWidth / 2),
                179 + (kPlatformHeight / 2));
        platform5.center =
            CGPointMake(8 + (kPlatformWidth / 2),
                81 + (kPlatformHeight / 2));
    }
}

-(void)gameStatePlayNormal {
    ballVelocity.y += gravity.y;

    if (touchState == kLeftDown) {
        ballVelocity.x -= 0.2;
    }
    if (touchState == kRightDown) {
        ballVelocity.x += 0.2;
    }
    if (ballVelocity.x > kMaxBallSpeed) {
        ballVelocity.x = kMaxBallSpeed;
    }
    if (ballVelocity.x < -kMaxBallSpeed) {
        ballVelocity.x = -kMaxBallSpeed;
    }

    if (ball.center.x > self.view.bounds.size.width) {
        ball.center = CGPointMake(0, ball.center.y);
    }

    if (ball.center.x < 0) {
        ball.center =
            CGPointMake(self.view.bounds.size.width, ball.center.y);
    }

    ball.center =
        CGPointMake(ball.center.x + ballVelocity.x,
            ball.center.y + ballVelocity.y);

    if (ball.center.y > self.view.bounds.size.height) {
        gameState = kStateGameOver;

    }
}

// Check for a bounce

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform1.frame)) {
    if (ball.center.y + 8 < platform1.center.y) {
        if (ballVelocity.y > 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -kJumpPower;
        }
    }
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform2.frame)) {
    if (ball.center.y + 8 < platform2.center.y) {
        if (ballVelocity.y > 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -kJumpPower;
        }
    }
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform3.frame)) {
    if (ball.center.y + 8 < platform3.center.y) {
        if (ballVelocity.y > 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -kJumpPower;
        }
    }
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform4.frame)) {
    if (ball.center.y + 8 < platform4.center.y) {
        if (ballVelocity.y > 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -kJumpPower;
        }
    }
}

if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform5.frame)) {
    if (ball.center.y + 8 < platform5.center.y) {
        if (ballVelocity.y > 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -kJumpPower;
        }
    }
}

-(void)touchesBegan:(NSSet *)
touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    if (gameState == kStateRunning) {
        UITouch *touch =[[event allTouches] anyObject];
        CGPoint location =[touch locationInView:touch.view];
        if (location.x < (self.view.bounds.size.width / 2)) {
            touchState = kLeftDown;
            ballVelocity.x -= 0.2;
        } else {
            touchState = kRightDown;
            ballVelocity.x += 0.2;
        }

    }
}

-(void)touchesEnded:(NSSet *)
touches withEvent:(UIEvent *) event
{
    touchState = kTouchesEnded;
}

-(void)viewDidUnload {
    [self setBall:nil];
    [self setPlatform1:nil];
    [self setPlatform2:nil];
    [self setPlatform3:nil];
    [self setPlatform4:nil];
    [self setPlatform5:nil];
    [self setBg:nil];
    [super viewDidUnload];
    // Release any retained subviews of the main view.
    // e.g. self.myOutlet = nil;
}

-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
}

-(void)viewWillDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewWillDisappear:animated];
}

-(void)viewDidDisappear:(BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidDisappear:animated];
}

-(BOOL) shouldAutorotateToInterfaceOrientation:(UIInterfaceOrientation) interfaceOrientation
{
    // Return YES for supported orientations
    return (interfaceOrientation !=
        UIInterfaceOrientationPortraitUpsideDown);
}

@end
```

I have the error around

```
if (CGRectIntersectsRect(ball.frame, platform1.frame)) {
    if (ball.center.y + 8 < platform1.center.y) {
        if (ballVelocity.y > 0) {
            ballVelocity.y = -kJumpPower;
        }
    }
}
```

I dont know why this is happening

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've run your code through `Lindent` (a small shell script around the `indent(1)` program with settings that the Linux kernel developers like; it isn't perfect, but it's a good start).

Once I did this, it was far easier to spot that your series of `if (CGRectIntersectsRect(..))` tests aren't actually *in* any function. They're at the top level of your source.

All statements and expressions must be within a function. (Declarations and global definitions can be at top-level.)

Figure out which function should "own" that series of routines and place them within the function body.